# Can I use any other language letters by default in C?

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and when trying to write a program in C with Turkish characters in it, the characters are not correct on terminal. Using `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");` works but am I going to write this code everytime a write a new program? Is there a way to "force" this by default so I can get rid of this process?

Comment: That depends on your environment settings usually. And those depends on operating system.

Comment: Can you elaborate that please?

Comment: `setlocale` is part of the POSIX standard. To avoid setting the locale in every program you most likely have to change the default locale of the entire operating system. The `update-locale` command might be what you're looking for depending on what flavor of OS you're using

Comment: @WillisHershey — `setlocale()` is part of Standard C too.

Comment: Additionally the visual output depends on the terminal. Assumed that you work on Windows, use "mode con cp select=..." on the terminal to select the [correct code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page). Hint: If you choose Unicode (code page 65001 for UTF-8), most characters of the world should work.

Comment: https://support.smartbear.com/testleft/docs/using/configuring/os/language-for-non-unicode-apps.html

Answer (score 0):

The C Standard [§7.11.1.1 The `setlocale` function ¶3-4](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.11.1.1p4) says:

> A value of `"C"` for locale specifies the minimal environment for C translation; a value of `""` for locale specifies the locale-specific native environment. Other implementation-defined strings may be passed as the second argument to `setlocale`.
>
> At program startup, the equivalent of
>
> ```
>     setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
> ```
>
> is executed.

Consequently, if you want a different locale to be in use, you have to override this with an explicit call to `setlocale()`.

The POSIX specification of [`setlocale()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setlocale.html) conforms to the C standard but also extends it, specify that the second argument can be:

> - `"POSIX"`
>   [CX] ⌦ Specifies the minimal environment for C-language translation called the POSIX locale. The POSIX locale is the default global locale at entry to main(). ⌫
> - `"C"`
>   Equivalent to "POSIX".
> - `""`
>   Specifies an implementation-defined native environment. [CX] ⌦  The determination of the name of the new locale for the specified category depends on the value of the associated environment variables, LC_* and LANG; see XBD Locale and Environment Variables. ⌫
> - A null pointer
>   Directs setlocale() to query the current global locale setting and return the name of the locale if `category` is not LC_ALL, or a string which encodes the locale name(s) for all of the individual categories if `category` is LC_ALL.

This means that if you write `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` at the start of `main()`, all users of the program stand the maximum chance of being able to use their preferred locale.